# PdfReader getNumberOfPages() returning only one page all the time

Tags: itext, pdf-reader

I have a code which creates byte input stream dynamically and then converts it into PDF. I am using iText 5.1.2 version. Code invokes getNumberOfPages() method on Pdfreader to iterate over it and build complete PDF but every time this method is returning 1. and only first page is being printed. Data which should go in second page is being lost.
When i see string content to be converted into PDF i can see the complete data coming from upstream there. Below is my code:

```
int getPageCount(String str) throws Exception{
    Document doc = new Document();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();;
    str = str.replaceAll("</lf>", "\n");
    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, out);
    doc.open();
    PdfReader reader;
    reader = new PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes()));
    int i = reader.getNumberOfPages();
    for (int page = 0; page < i;) {
        copy.addPage(copy.getImportedPage(reader, ++page));
    }
    copy.freeReader(reader);
    doc.close();
    out.flush();
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: Do I read your source correctly? You take a string, do some string manipulation, encode it to a byte array, and then try to read it as a PDF? It is luck you can read it add a PDF at all...

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand of your question, you're trying to estimate how many pages would be taken up by printing a certain string to a pdf document.

The better (iText7!!) way of doing this would be:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        System.out.println(i + "\t" + getPageCount(lipsum(i)));
}

static int getPageCount(String str)
{
    OutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(out);
    PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(writer);
    Document layoutDocument = new Document(pdfDocument);
    layoutDocument.add(new Paragraph(str));
    return pdfDocument.getNumberOfPages();
}

static String lipsum(int nofRepeats)
{
    String retval = "";
    String base = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
    for(int i=0;i<nofRepeats;i++)
    {
        retval += base;
    }
    return retval;
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a iText 7 answer while the question explicitly refers to version 5.1.2. To prevent frustration on the side of the readers of your answer you should at least make that clear in your answer.

Comment: Also, if you arent' bound to one particular version of iText, consider using pfdHTML.